# Why can't I install react/icons package?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have the latest versions of NodeJS and NPM installed on Windows. This error happens when I try to install the `react/icons` NPM package.

```
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/react/icons.git
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

Comment: If you're talking about [`react-icons`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-icons), the proper installation command would be `npm install react-icons` or `npm install @react-icons/all-files` depending on your project.

Comment: The error tells in plain english that it `Could not read from remote repository` because `publickey` authentication failed i.e. `Permission denied` for SSH user `git@github.com`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you are using will attempt a GitHub clone. Use this command:

```
npm install react-icons
```

or in simplest form

```
npm i react-icons
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try

> npm install react-icons or npm i react-icons

If you are using Linux or Ubuntu then

> npm install react-icons

or

> npm i react-icons

If you having Permission issue to Install then you can follow this

> sudo npm install react-icons

or

> sudo npm i react-icons